# fread showProgress as message

Tags: r, data.table, knitr

I am using `fread` to read in data as part of a `.Rnw` file I am working on. The file is big, `6` million rows, and I like the `showProgress` option. However, when I knit, the output appears in the final pdf. Elsewhere in the file, I print progress using `message()`, which I suppress in `opts_chunk`. Is there any way to print the progress as a `message` or in some other way that it doesn't appear in my final output?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You could set `options(datatable.showProgress = FALSE)` in your first code chunk. This will disable data table progress bar printing (by default) for the rest of the document.